# Visual studio 2010 git extention manage remotes unable to connect

Tags: git, github, git-extensions, git-remote

I am pretty sure I am making a trivial mistake. I am using using Git Source Control Provider for VS 2010 and Git Extension UI. I am completely new to git concepts and I am doing everything through UI and not using command prompt.

I created a repo and then a private and public key. Then I configured the remotes for the repo using the private key (Public was added to my account on GitHub). It all worked fine as I was able to push my local repo. To configure remote I used Git Extension in VS (Git -> Manage remotes).

Then I created another repo and tried to configure the remotes again using the same private key but it failed and showed the error "Unable to open connection: Host does not exist". I created another private/public key pair but it failed again with same message.

What am I doing wrong? Anyone? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I said, it had to be a trivial mistake. I was trying to push the new local repo using HTTPS url instead of SSH url. I used SSH url and everything is cool now.

Comment: Thank you Packer! I ran into the exact same issue w/ github and switching the URL from HTTPS to SSH saved my day.